# Can't Alter table due to Index PRIMARY is corrupted

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have a table which has around 3M rows(11GB Data). Everything was working fine but recently I faced a problem while Altering the table(adding new column). I am getting "Error Code: 1712. Index PRIMARY is corrupted" error.

I have tried to update table engine to InnoDb(although current engine also Innodb) but this table alteration also not run successful.I have tried to run below query

```
ALTER TABLE table_name ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

as this is live database so I can not run long running task which lock the table.

Comment: Step 1: Check if your backups exist, are up to date and are not corrupt (e.g. contain that table with data). Step 2: read answers to your question.

Comment: Thanks @Solarflare but I dont have backup with updated data